# How to Create a successive formula table from user input values in html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables, spreadsheet

I am working on a cash flow table. I want the given maturity value to multiply by the 2022 revenue every year. The revenue should be increasing yearly by the maturity percent. The same should happen for the Net income.

I have given an initial 2022 revenue, but this is arbitrary. I would like for the values to be shown in the table. Thanks for help.

```js
var revenue22 = 202;

function calculateBy() {
  var maturityvar = Number(document.getElementById("maturity").value);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: true;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

form {
  text-align: right;
}

td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 2px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #c55f5fcb;
}

input {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>(Insert Name Here) Net Profit Value Calculator</h1>
<form>
  <table>
    <caption>Simplified Business Free Cash Flow Model (millions) </caption>
    <tr>
      <th>YEAR:</th>
      <th>2018</th>
      <th>2019</th>
      <th>2020</th>
      <th>2021</th>
      <th>2022</th>
      <th>2023</th>
      <th>2024</th>
      <th>2025</th>
      <th>2026</th>
      <th>2027</th>
      <th>2028</th>
      <th>2029</th>
      <th>2030</th>
      <th>2031</th>
      <th>2032</th>
      <th>2033</th>
      <th>2034</th>
      <th>2035</th>
      <th>2036</th>
      <th>2037</th>
      <th>2038</th>
      <th>2038</th>
      <th>2039</th>
      <th>2040</th>
      <th>2041</th>
      <th>2042</th>
      <th>2044</th>
      <th>2046</th>
      <th>2047</th>
      <th>2048</th>
      <th>2049</th>
      <th>2050</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calc">
      <td>Revenue:</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>
        <script>
          Number(document.write(revenue22).value);
        </script>
      </td>
      <td>
        <script>
          Number(document.write(revenue23).value);
        </script>
      </td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="calc">
      <td style=> Net&nbspIncome:</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>
        <script>
          Number(document.write(income22).value);
        </script>
      </td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
      <td>x</td>
    </tr>
    </div>
  </table>
</form>
<br>
</form>
<p>
  <form name="npvdata">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td style=background-color:#756c6c;>Maturity (Growth) Rate (%)</td>
        <td style=background-color:#756c6c;><input type="number" id="maturity" value="10" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style=background-color:#756c6c;>Interest (Default) Rate (%):</td>
        <td style=background-color:#756c6c;><input type="number" id="interest" value="6" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</p>
<p1>
  </form>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onClick="calculateBy()" Value="Calculate" />
  </form>
  <br>
  </p2>
```

Comment: There are a number of issues here, but let's start by not using `document.write`. The approach you should be taking is building up your table data into a set of objects that contain keys matching your column headers and values that you intend to display. The goal is to create an array of those objects. Each object represents one row in your table. The array represents the collection of rows. Once you have that in place, you can create the entire table with a few lines of code (most of that HTML you've written will be unnecesary).

Comment: Thanks for the help, what should I do after I created the table Array. Thanks, Again, Noah. (What were the few lines of code that you were referencing? XD)

Comment: since you're taking a different approach, its best if you ask a new question. You can delete this one if you want. Just make sure you include that code that builds that array and ask about how to dynamically build and HTML Table with it.